# How to get AFHTTPRequestOperation to call selectors, not blocks, when completed?

Tags: iphone, ios, asihttprequest, grand-central-dispatch, afnetworking

`AFHTTPRequestOperation` likes to call GCD blocks when the request operation has been completed. Is there a way to get it to call method selectors instead? I am transitioning my app from `ASIHTTPRequest` to AFNetworking, and my app is built around selectors and not blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could call your selector inside of the completion block:

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:urlRequest
        success:^(NSURLRequest *completedURLRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSDictionary *json) {
            [self callMyCustomSuccessMethod:json];
        }
        failure:^(NSURLRequest *errorRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
            [self callMyCustomErrorMethod:error];
        }];
[operation start];
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if `AFHTTPRequestOperation` supports selector-based callbacks, but you can easily wrap a call to your selector in a block:

```
success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
   [myDelegate onSuccess:operation];
}
```

This would work for a callback method declared as:

```
- (void)onSuccess:(AFHTTPRequestOperation*)operation;
```